# Form submissions within app won't work on Iphone

Tags: php, iphone

I'm using the following code to submit a login form:

```
  <div data-role="content">
     <form id="test" method="post" action="login.php">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>User ID</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="userid" size="20" /></td>
          <br />
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="password" size="20" /></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="mysubmit"  value="Login" />

      </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

This form submission works fine on Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Safari on Windows. However, when I'm using Device Preview in Dreamweaver and trying it from my Iphone, I get 'error loading page' on all my form submits. If I put in `data-ajax="false"`, I then get

> '{"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"POST is not allowed"}'

when I submit my form. Also, I'm using local server for my sql server.

I even tried using test.php as the action instead of my login.php page with the following blank code for test.php and it still came up 'error loading page':

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried all this from an android phone also and still get 'error loading page' in Device Preview. This is my first app so once I can figure out this problem, I'll be full steam ahead.

Comment: You mean from safari browser?

Comment: The browser does not really matter on ios since every "custom" browser is forced by Apple to use the Safari web engine. Everything which has to do with web pages etc is the same on every ios browser

Comment: What is your websserver scenario? Local server? Web server? Which all browser do you check?

Comment: do you use jquery mobile? if yes, you must put data-ajax=false at form tag. <form id="test" method="post" action="test.php" data-ajax=false>

Comment: To answer all above questions, the browsers I've checked where it works fine on are Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Safari on Windows. I'm using device preview in Dreamweaver and trying it on my Iphone when I get 'error loading page' on all my form submits. If I put in data-ajax="false", I get '{"code":"MethodNotAllowedError","message":"POST is not allowed"} when I submit my form. Also I'm using local server for my sql server.

Answer (score -1):

Add ids to your inputs. Instead of

```
<input type="text" name="userid" size="20" />
```

Put

```
<input type="text" id="userid" name="userid" size="20" />
```

Comment: I just tried this and I still get 'error loading page'. But thanks.